# Mix audio files (.wav) / Add audio to viedo on android

Tags: android, audio, video, mixing

I am developing app, in which I want to :

1. Mix two audio files ( most probably .wav files ). Mixing here means, output file will sound like two audio files are being played at same time and **not concat.**
2. Adding audio to video.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a question. A question would be _"How do I mix two 16-bit stereo PCM audio streams and multiplex the result with a h264 video stream into an mp4 file?"_. Although, that would be very broad question, and therefore not particularly well-suited for StackOverflow. Explain what you've done so far, what problems you've encountered and narrow the question down as much as possible.

Comment: Or better yet, split this into two questions. Each have been answered numerous times on SO.